# How can you use the FIND command on a text file that uses CR but not LF?

Tags: batch-file

I don't know if it's actually possible to do, but I have a text file that contains some lines which use only the ascii Carriage Return (CR) character, and doesn't follow it with a Line Feed (LF) character.

My problem is that I'm trying to use the FIND command to search for a string in file, but I can't get it to return any of the lines with CR (It does return CR+LF lines, obviously).

Is there any way that I can search these lines using native batch commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exhaustively tested FINDSTR, and I know that it will treat the entire file as one line if it only has `<CR>` and no `<LF>`.

I haven't done the same level of testing with FIND, but I suspect it will have the same problem. But I can't say for sure at the moment.

---

***Edit 1***

I have confirmed (on Vista anyway), that FIND breaks lines strictly after `<LF>`, with or without the `<CR>` before it. The `<CR>` character is simply treated as another character.

You shouldn't have any problem searching for lines that have embedded `<CR>` in them. The problem will be how the output looks on the screen. Also, multiple logical lines will be treated as a single line (those "ending" with `<CR>`).

I created a test.txt file with the following structure

```
1<CR><LF>
2<CR><LF>
3<CR>4<CR>5<CR><LF>
6<CR><LF>
7<CR><LF>
```

And then used FIND against it

```
FIND "2" <test.txt
-> 2

FIND "3" <test.txt
-> 5

FIND "4" <test.txt
-> 5

FIND "5" <test.txt
-> 5

FIND "6" <test.txt
-> 6
```

The output looks weird when searching for 3 and 4, but it is actually correct. That is because 3, 4 and 5 are all on the same line. FIND prints out the entire line, but the carriage returns cause the 3 to be overwritten by the 4, and the 4 is overwritten by the 5. It becomes more obvious if I do `FIND "3" <test.txt >out.txt` - it produces a file of length 7 bytes.

You will get basically the same results if you use FINDSTR.

You cannot force FIND (or FINDSTR) to break lines at a lone `<CR>`. But you can preprocess your file to convert the lone `<CR>` chars into Windows standard line terminators using the following simple hybrid script. The script takes the name of the file to convert as the 1st and only parameter.

The meat of the conversion is done with JScript, and the rest with batch. It's probably silly to use a hybrid - the whole thing could have been done with JScript (or VBScript), but the hybrid was fun. And you can easily add additional batch commands as you see fit. For example, you could add your FIND command after the MOVE but before the EXIT /B.

Warning - the script over-writes the original text file. Remove the MOVE command if you want the modified version to be a separate file.

```
@if (@x)==(@y) @end /* harmless valid code for both batch and Jscript
::********* Batch Part **************************************************
:: This batch script calls the JScript below to normalize the end-of-line
:: for the contents of the file name passed in as parameter 1.
:: It redirects JScript to read its input from the file, and writes the
:: output to a new file. The batch script than moves the new file to 
:: replace the original.
::
:: You could put your FIND command after the MOVE and before the EXIT /B.
::
@echo off
<%1 cscript //e:jscript /nologo "%~f0" >"%~1.new"
move "%~1.new" "%~1" >nul
exit /b

*********** JScript Part **************************************
* This little script reads stdin, normalizes the end-of-line,
* and writes the result to stdout
*
* <CR><LF> -> no change
* <LF> without preceding <CR> -> <CR><LF>
* <CR> without following <LF> -> <CR><LF>
*/
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace( /\r/g, "\r\n" ) );
}
```

---

***Edit 2***

I just realized there is a totally non-destructive method to search the "lines" terminated by `<CR>` if I just slightly modify my script above. Besides making the necessary changes, I eliminated the comments.

The script now takes 2 arguments: "searchString", "fileName"

```
@if (@x)==(@y) @end /* harmless valid code for both batch and Jscript
::********* Batch Part **********************************************
@echo off
<%2 cscript //e:jscript /nologo "%~f0" | find "%~1"
exit /b

*********** JScript Part *******************************************/
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace( /\r/g, "\r\n" ) );
}
```